# initialize only some elements of array in java

Tags: java, arrays

So I want to skip the first and last elements of the array to initialize. What am I doing wrong?

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    //Write code here
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Input Rows: ");
    int m = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Input Columns: ");
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter values: ");
    int[][] arr = new int[m][n];

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (arr[i][j] == arr[0][0] || arr[i][j] == arr[m][n]) {
                continue;
            } else {
                arr[i][j] = sc.nextInt();
            }
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            System.out.print(arr[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

Here is my output:

```
Input Rows: 
3

Input Columns:
3

Entered Values:

0 0 0 

0 0 0 

0 0 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You compare the value of `arr[i][j]` with the value of `arr[0][0]`. You should instead compare `i==0 && j==0 || i==m -1 && j==n -1`

As your array was empty, and as you start the loop, arr[i][j] was equal to arr[0][0], skipping the first element. but for the next loop, arr[i][j] was still empty, and as you compare it to a non-initialised value, it's always true, skipping in each step

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    //Write code here
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Input Rows: ");
    int m = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Input Coloumns: ");
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter values: ");
    int[][] arr = new int[m][n];

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (i==0 && j==0 || i==m-1 && j==n-1) {
                continue;
            } else {
                arr[i][j] = sc.nextInt();
            }
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            System.out.print(arr[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

Comment: Id be careful with the order of operations. I suggest using parenthesis appropriately.

Comment: damn! such small mistake. Thanks a lot

Comment: Wrong, your condition can't be satisfied, as the loop invariants are `i <m` and `j<n`.

Comment: @ThomasTimbul thanks, i just remove the brackets forgetting the -1

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the if condition inside the loop like following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        if ((i == 0 && j==0) || (i == m -1 && j == n -1)) {
            continue;
        } else {
            arr[i][j] = sc.nextInt();
        }
    }

    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In this line:

```
if (arr[i][j] == arr[0][0] || arr[i][j] == arr[m][n]) {
```

You are testing for the equality of **values** within your array. You should be comparing whether the **indices** you are looking at are the beginning or end of the array.
That is to say, you want to compare whether (in pseudo code):

```
i==0 and j==0, OR i==max index in its dimension and j==max index in its dimension
```

I have deliberately omitted the literal answer, because this looks a tiny bit like homework.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to check whether the array items are equal, you just want to check whether the row and column are equal to the last and first.

Comment: you can do that for first element but how can you do it for last element?

Comment: This is not correct. The OP wants to skip elements `[0][0]` and `[m][n]`. Your code skips all the `[0][*]`, `[*][0]`, `[m][*]`, `[*][n]` elements.

Comment: Yeah, your'e right. I was read that wrong and I thought he wanted to skip the first and last row and columns. Will edit.